# Find the solution of $u_t = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(u^2 \cdot u_x)+q u^3$ for $u = P(t) \cdot Q(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

**My attempt**

$$u_t = P'(t)Q(x)$$

$$u_x = P(t)Q'(x)$$

$$u_{xx} = P(t) Q''(x)$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(u^2 \cdot u_x)=2uu_x^2+u^2u_{xx} \quad \Rightarrow \ 2P(t)Q(x)(P(t)Q'(x))^2+(P(t)Q(x))^2P(t)Q''(x)$$

$$q u^3 \quad \Rightarrow \quad q P^3(t)Q^3(x)$$

Thus, the RHS looks like this:

$$2P(t)Q(x)(P(t)Q'(x))^2+(P(t)Q(x))^2P(t)Q''(x) + P^3(t)Q^3(x)$$

$$2P^3(t)Q(x)(Q'(x))^2+P^3(t)Q^2(x)Q''(x) + P^3(t)Q^3(x)$$

$$P^3(t) \cdot (2Q(x)(Q'(x))^2+Q^2(x)Q''(x)+Q^3(x))$$

The LHS looks like this:

$$P'(t)Q(x)$$

As $Q(x) \neq 0$ (otherwise, $u = 0$ and that's not what we want), we can divide it by $Q(x)$ on both sides:

$$P'(t) = P^3(t) \cdot (2(Q'(x)^2+Q(x)Q''(x)+Q^2(x))$$

$$\Leftrightarrow $$

$$\frac{P'}{P^3} = \lambda = 2(Q')^2+QQ''+Q^2$$

And here's the problem: I must've made a mistake somewhere, as I get very complicated solutions if I try to calculate these ODEs with Mathematica (the one for $P$ is simple, as it's $P = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(C - \lambda t)}}$, but the solution for $Q$ is very complicated, so it can't be right).

Maybe we have to make a substitution beforehand? I've written down in my notes that $k=1, \alpha=2, \beta=3$ but I don't know what their purpose is, I only know that in one example we made the substitution

$$u = e^{\alpha} \bar{u}, \quad t = e^{\beta}\bar{t}, \quad x = e^{\gamma} \bar{x} $$

Comment: Your approach is correct, but the factor $q$ was dropped somewhere. The equation for $Q$ can be simplified somewhat to the form $z'' = 3 \lambda z^{1/3} - 3 q z$ by setting $z = Q^3$. This can be turned into a first order equation for $z$ after multiplying with $z'$. However, then things become complicated indeed.

Comment: What is exacly the little $q$ ? a constant  ?

Comment: Why can't a complicated solution for $Q$ be correct?

Comment: @EliBartlett Because our Prof usually gives us problems to solve which do not involve complicated solutions

Comment: @user577215664 To be honest, I don't really know as it's not stated in the problem. I reckon it changes the way we calculate the differential equation, if we assume $q$ to be a function, rather than a constant?

Comment: If $q$ is a constant than it's easier to solve the DE otherwise it's more complicated For $q$ constant then the DE can be integrated to a first order DE with $p=dQ/dx$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
QQ''+2(Q')^2+qQ^2=\lambda,
\end{align}
under the integrating factor $2Q^3Q'$ we have
\begin{align}
Q^4(Q')^2+\frac{q}{3}Q^6=\frac\lambda2 Q^4+k_1,
\end{align}
with reduction to quadrature
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sqrt6 Q^2\mathrm dQ}{\sqrt{-2qQ^6+3\lambda Q^4+k_1}}=k_2\pm x.
\end{align}

Comment: So this means that there is no application for $k=1, \alpha = 2, \beta = 3$ here? Because I think there must be some sort of application of that here, like doing a change of variables like I suggested with $\bar{u}$ etc?

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer just a hint:
$$u_t = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(u^2 \cdot u_x)+q u^3$$
You can avoid lots of calculation just rewrite it:
$$3u_t = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(u^3 )+3q u^3$$
$$3\dfrac {P'(t)}{P^3(t)} =\lambda=\dfrac {1}{Q}\left( \frac{d^2}{d x^2}(Q^3 )+3q Q^3\right)$$
Then change the variable for the DE with $Q(x)$
$$ \frac{d^2 Q^3(x)}{d x^2}+3q Q^3(x)=\lambda Q(x)$$
For $q$ constant substitute:
$$p=\dfrac {dQ}{dx}$$
$$p\dfrac {dp}{dQ}=\dfrac {d^2Q}{dx^2}$$
$$ p\frac{dp}{dQ}+3q Q^3(x)=\lambda Q(x)$$
This DE is separable.

Comment: This sounds interesting, why can we rewrite the original equation like this?